# how to navigate css element in protractor based e2e tests, using Xpath?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, protractor, frontend, element

in Chrome dev tools > giving me this xpath

```
//*[@id="OvForm"]/basic-Item-fields/div[1]/div/div[3]/detail-label[1]/p/span/strong
```

Comment: I am willing to know the best practice by experienced Front End Devs.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to worry about the CSS XPath. Just use the element ID.

```
element(by.id('OIForm'))
```

If you really want to use the CSS:

```
element(by.css('.detail-label p span strong'))
```

But you might need to tweak that. Better to use the ID.